# Cron job wget writing files to server?

Tags: linux, cron

I was just looking at our server root and one of our old developers who has left seems to have a cron job running daily which is writing a file every day to the server root.

I had a look at the daily cron jobs and I guess this is the culprit as it's the only wget (the others are PHP scripts which I know run silently):

```
wget http://www.example.com/?option=com_portal&view=ops&tmpl=component >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Each day the server root has a file like this written:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root      11987 May 12 03:45 login.360
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root      11987 May 13 03:45 login.361
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root      11987 May 14 03:45 login.362
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root      11987 May 15 03:45 login.363
```

A new one for every day. The content of the file is the HTML page source. How can I safely modify the cron job to stop any output like this, until I do some further investigations into removing this cron job altogether?

Comment: Do `crontab -e` and comment (`#`) the offending line!

Comment: What does crontab -e do? I don't want to comment the line out yet as I haven't established the importance of the PHP script that is running (trying to decipher the spaghetti code and need to speak to some people who are not available at the moment).

Comment: So you don't want to comment out the wget line, but you don't want the cron job to download the html page everyday via the wget line? Confused.

Comment: No I am just trying to safely establish what the developer and his script was trying to do first. The URL points to a component within a Joomla site, but the component is a full MVC app so the request goes through some routing - you cannot run the PHP script directly, which I guess is why he's done it as a wget. My question basically is how can I still request the page but prevent it from outputting it to the server root?

Comment: I guess removing `>/dev/null 2>&1` from the end will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My question basically is how can I still request the page but prevent it from outputting it to the server root?*

How about making `wget` dump the data to `/dev/null`?

```
wget -O/dev/null http://www.example.com/blab
```

Comment: Its doesn't create files right now, but it sends email,